# How can I reuse the result of a SPARQL query to another query?

Tags: jquery, sparql, reusability

For example I have this query

```
SELECT ?x
WHERE {?x :has_input "z"}
```

then i want to use the result/s of `?x` as object to another query

```
SELECT ?y
WHERE {?y :uses "x"}
```

Any ideas how to achieve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not using the result from the first query in the second query in your example.  You're using a variable named `?x` in the first, and the string `"x"` in the second.  Are you looking to query for the actual value that the first query returned, or its string representation?

Comment: How are you running these queries?  Many APIs have a way of substituting some values into a query (though this will probably only work for non-anonymous resources and literals, and probably not for blank nodes).

Comment: Thanks for the accept, and I'm glad I was able to help!  Do you mind commenting on which of the solutions addressed your need, just for the sake of helping other users find the question?

Comment: Yes I was looking to query for the actual value the first query . returned. I am running these queries through jena and an external owl file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of the example, let's define some data:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .

:node0 :has_input "w", "z" .
:node1 :has_input "x", "y" .
:node2 :has_input "y", "z" .
:node3 :uses :node2 .
:node4 :uses :node1 .
```

Based on this data,  and with specifying any particular API (because you didn't), you've got a few SPARQL level options.  The first is simply combining the queries, which is easy enough in this case:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select ?y where { 
  ?x :has_input "z" .
  ?y :uses ?x .
}

$ arq --data data.n3 --query combined-query.sparql 
----------
| y      |
==========
| :node3 |
----------
```

Another option is to use a subquery

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select ?y where { 
  {
    select ?x where { 
      ?x :has_input "z" .
    }
  }
  ?y :uses ?x .
}


$ arq --data data.n3 --query subquery.sparql
----------
| y      |
==========
| :node3 |
----------
```

A third, which may be what you actually need, if you have to execute the queries separately, is to execute a query that finds values for `?x` for you, and then execute a query that finds `?y`, but with the `?x` values embedded with [`values`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data).  The first query looks like and returns:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select ?x where { 
  ?x :has_input "z" .
}

$ arq --data data.n3 --query xquery.sparql
----------
| x      |
==========
| :node2 |
| :node0 |
----------
```

Then, based on those values, you create the query for `?y`:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select ?y where { 
  values ?x { :node2 :node0 }
  ?y :uses ?x .
}

$ arq --data data.n3 --query yquery.sparql
----------
| y      |
==========
| :node3 |
----------
```